# Get KeyValuePair into Array from string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a project and I can't figure out how to go about doing it. I'm trying to do with Regex but fairly new to it.

I have a string such as `WHERE MyColumn='1's'' AND MyColumn='Test's''"`

I have the following regex in PHP

```
$found = array();
preg_match("/\s=\s'.*'|\s.*='.*'\s/", $whereQuery, $found);
```

In my array I have the following

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  MyColumn='1's'' 
)
```

So it's almost there, except I am expecting the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  MyColumn='1's'' 
    [1] =>  MyColumn='Test's'
)
```

Comment: `preg_match` only return first match. If want multiple matches, use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Use an SQL parser. Stop to try to parse the SQL language with regex, it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `preg_match_all` with this simplified regex:

```
preg_match_all('/\w+\h*=\h*\S+/', $whereQuery, $found);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL2xU0/1)

Comment: Wow that is much simpler. Works great